# Can a SqlUserDefinedAggregate be a derived class?

Tags: c#, sqlclr

I'm attempting to write some bitwise aggregate functions for a project I'm working on. What I have below is a working implementation for an aggregate where the operator is bitwise-or.

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;

namespace BitwiseAggregates
{
    [Serializable]
    [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
        Format.UserDefined,
        MaxByteSize = 8000,
        IsInvariantToNulls = false,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = true,
        IsInvariantToOrder = true
    )]
    public class BitwiseOrAggregate : IBinarySerialize
    {
        private BitArray Accumulator { get; set; }
        private bool IsFirstValue { get; set; }
        private bool IsNull { get; set; }

        public void Init()
        {
            IsFirstValue = true;
            IsNull = false;
        }
        public void Accumulate(SqlBinary Values)
        {
            if (Values.IsNull == false && this.IsNull == false)
            {
                if (this.IsFirstValue == true)
                {
                    this.Accumulator = FromSqlBinary(Values);
                    this.IsFirstValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    BitArray tempBA = FromSqlBinary(Values);
                    this.Accumulator = this.Accumulator.Or(tempBA);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IsNull = true;
            }
        }
        public void Merge(BitwiseOrAggregate that)
        {
            if (this.Accumulator.Length != that.Accumulator.Length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("All values must be the same length");
            }

            if (that.IsNull)
            {
                this.IsNull = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Accumulator = this.Accumulator.Or(that.Accumulator);
            }
        }
        public SqlBinary Terminate()
        {
            if (IsNull == true)
            {
                return SqlBinary.Null;
            }
            else
            {
                return new SqlBinary(FromBitArray(Accumulator));
            }
        }

        // Methods for IBinarySerialize
        public void Read(BinaryReader r)
        {
            IsFirstValue = r.ReadBoolean();
            IsNull = r.ReadBoolean();

            if (IsNull == false)
            {
                int bytesToRead = r.ReadInt32();

                byte[] ba = r.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);

                Accumulator = new BitArray(ba);
            }
        }
        public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
        {
            w.Write(IsFirstValue);
            w.Write(IsNull);

            if (IsNull == false)
            {
                byte[] ba = FromBitArray(Accumulator);

                int bytesToWrite = ba.Length;
                w.Write(bytesToWrite);

                w.Write(ba);
            }
        }

        // Helper methods
        protected BitArray FromSqlBinary(SqlBinary bytes)
        {
            return new BitArray((byte[])bytes);
        }
        protected byte[] FromBitArray(BitArray ba)
        {
            int returnLength = ba.Length / 8;
            byte[] retVal = new byte[returnLength];

            ba.CopyTo(retVal, 0);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

In looking to implement the next aggregate (using bitwise-and), I evaluated all of the methods and all but `Accumulate` and `Merge` will be the same. In an attempt to not repeat myself, I changed my code to this:

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;

namespace BitwiseAggregates
{
    [Serializable]
    [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
        Format.UserDefined,
        MaxByteSize = 8000,
        IsInvariantToNulls = false,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = true,
        IsInvariantToOrder = true
    )]
    public class BitwiseOrAggregate : BitwiseAggregate
    {
        public void Accumulate(SqlBinary Values)
        {
            if (Values.IsNull == false && this.IsNull == false)
            {
                if (this.IsFirstValue == true)
                {
                    this.Accumulator = FromSqlBinary(Values);
                    this.IsFirstValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    BitArray tempBA = FromSqlBinary(Values);
                    this.Accumulator = this.Accumulator.Or(tempBA);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IsNull = true;
            }
        }
        public void Merge(BitwiseOrAggregate that)
        {
            if (this.Accumulator.Length != that.Accumulator.Length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("All values must be the same length");
            }

            if (that.IsNull)
            {
                this.IsNull = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Accumulator = this.Accumulator.Or(that.Accumulator);
            }
        }
    }

    public class BitwiseAggregate : IBinarySerialize
    {
        protected BitArray Accumulator { get; set; }
        protected bool IsFirstValue { get; set; }
        protected bool IsNull { get; set; }
        public void Init()
        {
            IsFirstValue = true;
            IsNull = false;
        }

        public SqlBinary Terminate()
        {
            if (IsNull == true)
            {
                return SqlBinary.Null;
            }
            else
            {
                return new SqlBinary(FromBitArray(Accumulator));
            }
        }

        // Methods for IBinarySerialize
        public void Read(BinaryReader r)
        {
            IsFirstValue = r.ReadBoolean();
            IsNull = r.ReadBoolean();

            if (IsNull == false)
            {
                int bytesToRead = r.ReadInt32();

                byte[] ba = r.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);

                Accumulator = new BitArray(ba);
            }
        }
        public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
        {
            w.Write(IsFirstValue);
            w.Write(IsNull);

            if (IsNull == false)
            {
                byte[] ba = FromBitArray(Accumulator);

                int bytesToWrite = ba.Length;
                w.Write(bytesToWrite);

                w.Write(ba);
            }
        }

        // Helper methods
        protected BitArray FromSqlBinary(SqlBinary bytes)
        {
            return new BitArray((byte[])bytes);
        }
        protected byte[] FromBitArray(BitArray ba)
        {
            int returnLength = ba.Length / 8;
            byte[] retVal = new byte[returnLength];

            ba.CopyTo(retVal, 0);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Through a little experimentation, it seems that neither `Init()` nor `Terminate()` are making it into the SqlUserDefinedAggregate. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe declare all methods virtual on base class and override in inherited class?

Comment: Interesting thought. For context, I'm running with scissors here (i.e. I'm a DBA that very occasionally writes application code). What is the theoretical basis for why that would work? My understanding is declaring a method as virtual allows it to be overridden in a base class. Say I declared `Init()` as virtual in the base class. That would allow (but not obligate) me to override it in the derived class. If I understand your suggestion, needing to override in derived classes would be antithetical to my goal (i.e. "don't repeat yourself").

Comment: Sorry I've reread your question again and what I said doesn't make sense in this setup.

Comment: But in general I suspect that, because there is no interface those Init, Terminate etc methods belong to (and you only decorate class with attribute) - it searches for methods with certain names and signature, probably via reflection. There is reflection BindingFlag.DeclaredOnly which will only return members declared by given type but not inherited from parent types. It might be it uses this flag and as such does not see Init and Terminate methods declared by parent class.

Comment: Another guess - maybe mark parent BitwiseAggregate with Serializable attribute too?

Comment: Ooh... I think your comment led me in a good direction! In my derived class, I'm explicitly implementing `Init()` and `Terminate()` that just explicitly call the corresponding method from `base`. So `new public void Init() { base.Init(); }`

Comment: That's a bit ugly but an option too if it works :)

Comment: I agree - it's not my favorite. So maybe "good direction" was a charitable characterization. :) But there's something in the tool chain that's expecting explicit implementations of all of the required methods. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯